# Compare double ids, group into one

Tags: sql

I have a table "stats" that consists **3 ids and qty**.

From this table, I want to return **id_part, id_proj and qty**.

[image]

The solution is partly here, the only problem is that when the ids **are double**, it should show **only one row with summed qty**.

For example:

P1, J4, 1700

P3, J1, 600

P3, J4, 1700

```
SELECT id_part, id_proj, qty
FROM stats
ORDER BY id_part, id_proj;
```

[image]

I have tried with case, also I somehow wanted to compare first row with second, but no luck.

Comment: Simply `SUM(qty)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Group By` with `sum(qty)` on id_part to get a single result.

Code:

```
SELECT id_part, id_proj, sum(qty)
FROM stats
Group BY id_part
ORDER BY id_part, id_proj;
```

Comment: Thank you your solution works. My next atempt was almost the same but the qty should not be in the GROUP BY like i tried to put it.                                                                     SELECT id_part, id_proj, sum(qty)
FROM stats
GROUP BY id_part, id_proj, qty
ORDER BY id_part, id_proj;